# Include header from glibc

Tags: c, cmake, include, glibc

I've discovered a serious bottleneck in my project - about a quarter of overall execution time is wasted in `tzset` function (called by `mktime`).

I examined [tzset sources](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/time/tzset.c.html) (the code, starting from line 378) and found that setting **TZ** environment variable once will considerably reduce its execution time, for it reads a timezone file (for example `/usr/local/etc/zoneinfo` in my OS) if **TZ** environment variable isn't set.

I would read this file and set the environment variable, but the location of the file may differ on different planforms. So, what I'm going to do is to somehow reuse the code `tzset` uses for these purposes.
This may seem easy, just include the header `tzset` uses for locating and retrieving timezone info, and use this functionality :)

```
#include <timezone/tzfile.h>
```

but I really don't know how to do it, I mean using glibc headers. Compiler doesn't know this header (my IDE, Clion, doesn't see it too). I really stuck with this.

Comment: You have two basic choices. Add to your `configure` script (you do know how to write `autoconf` scripts -- which is pretty much a mandatory skill for anyone developing on non-proprietary POSIX-based operating systems -- right?) that searches for zoneinfo in a fixed set of locations, and use that to compile-in a runtime constant. Or, obtain the location from some environment variable, that must be set before running your application. This situation is really what `autoconf`, and the rest of the GNU toolchain, is designed for.

Comment: "Use autotools" isn't a helpful answer to someone asking how to do something in CMake.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include a [platform check](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Write_Platform_Checks) for tzinfo.h in your `CMakeLists.txt`. Example:

```
INCLUDE (CheckIncludeFiles)
# usage: CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES (<possible header locations> <RESULT_VARIABLE> )

if (${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Linux")
  CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES("timezone/tzfile.h;sys/tzfile.h" HAVE_TZFILE_H)
endif(${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME} STREQUAL "Linux")
```

You can then use `#ifdef HAVE_TZFILE_H`

If you aren't worried about verifying the content of the file, you can also use [`FIND_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_file.html) instead which is a little faster. (`CheckIncludeFiles` actually uses a small .c file and `#include`s the header attempting to compile it.)

`find_file (<VAR> NAMES name PATHS paths... NO_DEFAULT_PATH)`